# Event sourcing: splitting event in more detailed

Tags: event-sourcing

While user registration process in my domain several actions occur: user created (with email/password or with linked social network account), user login is done.

I have (see) two options how to register the events:

- One `UserRegistred` event (which contains all the info, password hashes, external social accounts)
- Multiple events `UserCreated`, `UserPasswordSet`, `UserExternalAccountLinked`, `UserLoggedIn`

Events from second option (`UserPasswordSet`, `UserExternalAccountLinked`, `UserLoggedIn`) may appear on their own later while performing corresponded operations.

I understand that question and options may be subjective, but I would like hear opinions of experienced ES/DDD users about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be experienced, but I think it's simpler output multiple events rather than having a complex simple event.

The pros are:

- Simplicity - projections (including the aggregate itself) and other event handlers don't need to understand a complex UserRegistered event as well as the fine grained events
- Less churn on the event schemas - e.g. if you change details of your authentication events, fewer event types will need to change (since there's no UserRegistered event to change)
- Clarity - the events better capture the sequence of state changes involved in user registration

I can think of a minor con:

- Non-atomic registration. It's likely projections could handle a single user registered event and atomically create the read model in a state that the client can immediately query. If you have multiple events, the read model might handle them one by one, meaning the user may be temporarily in a half-registered state, that you might not want to handle in your clients.

  - This can be avoided by having your read projection consume all available events and make its update in a single transaction, so that the sequence of events causes only a single transaction commit, and hence you never see a half-registered user. This is more efficient in any case, but might not be that simple, depending on your read store.
  - Alternatively, you can automatically filter out half-registered users when querying the service